# ASP.Net email sending with Gmail not working via port 587

Tags: asp.net, gmail

I tried the following code to send email via ASP.Net 2.0:

```
  int port=465;
  //int port=587;
  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", port);
  smtpClient.Timeout = 260000;
  smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mygmail@gmail.com", password);
  smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials =false;
  smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
  //Setting From , To and CC
  mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
  mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("myaddress@mydomain.com"));
  mail.Body = contents;
  smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

I checked the solutions and there are 2 ports that are used: 465 and 587. Port 587 seemed to work 2-3 years ago.

I tried both, here are the results:

- port 465, with 4 minutes timeout: always times out on my localhost and on a different server from ISP
- port 587, with 4 minutes timeout: I immediately get this response both in localhost and in ISP site:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the port 587 and first set the `UseDefaultCredentials` and then set the `Credentials`

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials =false;

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mygmail@gmail.com", password);
```

if you set credentials first, you will lost it when you set `UseDefaultCredentials` as false

Comment: Strange, on my ISP site it still shows 5.5.1 error.

Comment: Google sent an email that the ISP site is trying to use my account and they prevented it. I should add it as a reliable client.

Comment: @Nestor, your problem having two issues, one can be fixed by my answer. you better add another answer  or update the question itself about how you fix the isp site issue, anyway glad to hear that you able to find a solution